# Aumentar un número

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy haciendo un programa que lo que haga es que al presionar un botón que ocupa toda la pantalla sume 1 a un span que está dentro de ese botón, el problema que tengo es que al darle en vez de poner 1,2,3,4 sucesivamente que es lo que quiero, lo que me sale es 0,1,12,123,1234... Gracias de antemano

```js
function inicio() {
        let num = 0;
        let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
        let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

        boton.onclick = function (e) {
            numero.textContent = parseInt(numero.textContent + num);
            num++;
        }
    }
```

```css
#boton {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97.5vh;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        font-size: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()" ;>
  <div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero"></span></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

De nuevo gracias de antemano.

Comment: Gracias, ya me ha funcionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es mas que nada, en esta parte del codigo.

```
(numero.textContent + num);
```

Estas concatenando, en vez de mandar solo num.

```js
function inicio() {
        let num = 0;
        let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
        let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

        boton.onclick = function (e) {
            numero.textContent = parseInt(num);
            num++;
        }
    }
```

```css
#boton {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97.5vh;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        font-size: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()" ;>
  <div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero"></span></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Es un clásico error en Javascript: estás *sumando* textos (concatenando) en lugar de números

```js
function inicio() {
        let num = 0; //number
        let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
        let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

        boton.onclick = function (e) {
            console.log('tenemos un', typeof numero.textContent);
            numero.textContent = parseInt(numero.textContent + num);
            num++;
        }
    }
```

```css
#boton {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97.5vh;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        font-size: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()" ;>
  <div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero"></span></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

La solución es asegurarte de usar números:

```js
function inicio() {
    let num = 0; //number
    let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
    let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

    boton.onclick = function (e) {
        console.log('tenemos un', typeof numero.textContent);
        numero.textContent = num++;
    }
}
```

```css
#boton {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97.5vh;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        font-size: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()" ;>
  <div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero"></span></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

te quedaria de la siguiente manera , solamente necesitas mostrar el `num++` en el `textcontent`

```js
function inicio() {
        let num = 0;
        let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
        let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

        boton.onclick = function (e) {
            numero.textContent = num++;
             
        }
    }
```

```css
#boton {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97.5vh;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        font-size: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()" ;>
  <div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero"></span></button>
  </div>
</body>
```